# JavaScript function to edit original object

Tags: javascript, variables

Is there any way, in JavaScript, to write a function like:

```
var a = "Hello"

function change(variable, value) {
//Code that edits original variable, not the variable argument
}

alert(a)
change(a, "World!");
alert(a);
```

And this would output first "Hello", and then "World!". Is there any way to write a function like that?

Comment: No, but you can encapsulate the value in an object, and modify it as a property of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but a close alternative is to treat `a` as a JS object:

```
var a = { value : "Hello" };

function change(variable, value) {
    //I'll let you work this part out
}

alert(a.value);
change(a, "World!");
alert(a.value);
```

Comment: Thanks, force of habit :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do that by using JavaScript Closures;

```
var obj = (function() {
           var x = 'hello'; 
           return { 
                  get: function() { 
                       return x; 
                  }, 
                  set: function(v) { 
                       x = v; }
                  }
                  })();

obj.get(); // hello
obj.set('world');
obj.get(); // world
```

You can only the change the value of the variable using the get and set functions.